# Calling reified inline function with wrong inferred type: no compiler error

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

Can anyone explain why there's no compiler error when I use an inline function in a function call with the wrong inferred type, yet there's a compiler error when I explicitly mention the type?

```
interface Foo

class FooBar : Foo

inline fun <reified T: Foo> createFoo() : T {
    return T::class.java.getConstructor().newInstance()
}

fun fooFun(foo: String) {}

fun main() {
    val foo1 = createFoo<FooBar>() // all good 
    val foo2 = createFoo<String>() // compiler error
    val foo3: String = createFoo() // compiler error
    
    fooFun(createFoo()) // all good at compile time, fails at runtime: why? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
}
```

I would expect that calling `fooFun(createFoo())` should also result in a compiler error.

Comment: This is likely a flaw in the compiler. At compile time, reified inline functions are injected into their invocation sites, so that last line will actually look like the following after compilation:
`fooFun(String::class.java.getConstructor().newInstance())`
For what ever reason, the compiler is not catching that particular inferred type as invalid for the type constraint. So instead at runtime you get a String object which will probably throw an IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: Weirdly the actual error at runtime is a `ClassCastException` from `Object` to `Foo`.

Comment: That actually makes more sense than an IllegalArgumentException